# They played "averagely" today?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, adverbs

I am wondering if this adverb is ever used or if you would restructure to "Their performance today was average." or something similar. Which adverb could I use in the above sentence?

Comment: Note that ***averagely*** isn't at all common, and many people would probably say it's effectively "non-standard", so it's best avoided. You might consider something like *They played unexceptionally / uninspiringly / boringly*, but personally I think you're better off with your own suggestion - particularly if you specifically want to focus on the fact that it was just "average", without necessarily implying too much else.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As FumbleFingers mentions in his comment, "averagely" is a word, but it's not one people seem to use.  There are many other words you can use in this context, "adequately", "unremarkably", "unexceptionally", "competently", "blandly", "tolerably", "passably" and so on.  All of these are probably better used as an adjective, as in:

> Their performance today was unexceptional/ acceptable/ adequate/ etc.

or before the noun:

> They gave an unremarkable performance today (but still managed to beat the other team).

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use *okay* adverbially there:

> They played okay today.

According to [M-W.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/okay), *okay* as an adjective or adverb can mean "fairly good : not very good or very bad", which to me encompasses the "average" (especially as in "unremarkable", "normal") sense that I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be *so-so*:

> They played so-so today.

[M-W.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so-so) defines *so-so* as "neither very good nor very bad : fair or average" and allows its use as an adverb.  (They also provide a few synonyms, such as "middling" and "tolerably".)